# Reaching RDS in private VPC when public VPC only has Fargate containers

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have fargate containers communicating with RDS in a private VPC. Fargate containers are running in public VPC; however, fargate containers cannot be SSHed from my knowledge so I cannot tunnel through the containers to reach database with my DataGrip client.

In such case, what would be the best way to reach privately hosted RDS? Is only option to create an EC2 instance that would act as a bridge in the public subnet?

Comment: I think you could ssh into a container on fargate. One example of doing that is shown [here](https://medium.com/ci-t/9-steps-to-ssh-into-an-aws-fargate-managed-container-46c1d5f834e2)

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right trail, you will need to use an EC2 instance and create a bastion host. That setup should work as a proxy to incoming traffic. [Read more about bastion hosts here](https://aws.amazon.com/en/quickstart/architecture/linux-bastion/).